# Преобразование exe-шника, созданного с помощью Nuitka обратно в py

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nuitka

Имеется .exe файл, написан на Python , собранный с помощью Nuitka. Не знаю как переделать его обратно в .py.

Pyinstxtractor выдает Error : Unsupported pyinstaller version or not a pyinstaller archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuitka транслирует код python в код на си, потом этот код компилируется в машинный код:

> Nuitka translates the Python modules into a C level program that then uses libpython and static C files of its own to execute in the same way as CPython does.

[Цитата из readme репозитория на гитхабе](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka)

Обратная операция фактически невозможна. Можно открыть экзешник дизассемблером, и посмотреть на ассемблерный код, или получить сишный псеводокод (который без сильного допиливания обратно не скомпилируется), но изначальный python код вернуть не получится.